# Invalid Session id (Connect Failure) randomly when running automated tests

Tags: automated-testing, chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I've been new to automated test creation and have been dipping my hands on it recently. Every test seems to be running successfully individually except whenever I run them all together sequentially, sometimes, on random tests, I get an invalid session id error as described in the title. This happens completely randomly and on random tests too, it isn't always on the same ones where I get failures like that.
I tried browsing to see if it was something related to my base automated test, perhaps it could be related to drivers overlapping but couldn't reach a solution that would make this stop happening.
Here's the base I have for all my tests:

```
    public class BaseAutomatedTest : IDisposable
    {
    public IWebDriver Driver;

    public BaseAutomatedTest()
    {
        Driver = new TestDriverFactory().CreateDriver();
        Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ~BaseAutomatedTest()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        //// Cleanup
        if (Driver != null)
        {
            Driver.Close();

            Driver.Quit();

            Driver.Dispose();
        }
    }}
```

All tests inherit the code above. Any ideas of what could possibly be going wrong? The internet made me inclined that my issue is with this base/driver initialization/closure but none of the solutions I've found seem to work. 
I'm using Selenium paired up with Chromedriver to execute my tests.

Edit: I've added a stack trace of an example of the error I'm getting. I'm using Chromedriver77 for this and I don't always get this error on this specific test, it's just for example purposes since it passes successfully sometimes:

```
    System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
---- OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : invalid session id
---- OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51059/session/68f5fa5dfe6981eb48b5cdaf26f83abd/window. The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was: Unable to connect to the remote server
-------- System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
------------ System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:51059
----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException) -----
RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
ChangeUsernameTest.NavigateTo() line 91
ChangeUsernameTest.ChangeUsername_ConclusionNavigateToLinkValidation_Success(String username, String password) line 979
----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException) -----
HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
RemoteWebDriver.Close()
BaseFunctionalTest.Dispose(Boolean disposing) line 34
BaseFunctionalTest.Dispose() line 22
ReflectionAbstractionExtensions.DisposeTestClass(ITest test, Object testClass, IMessageBus messageBus, ExecutionTimer timer, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) line 79
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

Comment: Could you paste stacktrace and the exact error you are getting? Also please post version of chromedriver and selenium.

Comment: @Prome added aditional information on EDIT section

Comment: @E.T. have you tried opening a ticket on Selenium github?

Comment: Have you solved this random issue?
I am struggling with a similar thing that happens on Windows Machines only, Mac is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use C#, but as far as I know you should not be using `WebDriver` once `Quit()` was called.

Also, [Selenium docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_Quit.htm) says `Close()` and `Dispose()` are already covered in `Quit()` so no need to call it again.

Comment: I've tried to adjust my solution based on your suggestion but nothing has changed in terms of test execution, I keep getting the completely random invalid session errors on random tests.